# Android - Ignoring Catch Clause?

Tags: android, try-catch, notepad

Can "catch" clause be ignored? I have this code and what I wanna do is to scan all words containing a specific string and store them in String res.

But the code I have now does not iterate through the loop because it stops when the "catch" clause interrupts. Is there a way to ignore catch clause and just let the "try" continue the loop until it reaches the end of file?

```
String delimiter = " - ";
String[] del;
String res = new String();

if(curEnhancedStem.startsWith("a"))
{
InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.definitiona); 
try {
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
      String s = in.readLine();
      while(s != null)
        {
             s = in.readLine();
             del = s.split(delimiter);
             if (del[0].contains(curEnhancedStem))
             {
                 res = res + s + "\n\n";
             }
        }
          return res;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
                // nothing to do here
            }   
        }
```

Comment: It goes to the catch clause because there is an exception in your code. Sending it back to the try clause is unlikely to help you, as in most cases you'll just run into the exception again. Try debugging your code and fixing the exception instead.

Comment: Yes catch clause can be ignored, by not writing it in code.

Comment: If i dont write a "catch" clause, I get an error saying that "readline()" should be surrounded with a catch clause or I should put Finally below try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thing you must be getting exception inside while, So try this.

```
  try {
  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
  String s = in.readLine();
  while(s != null)
    {
     try{
         s = in.readLine();
         del = s.split(delimiter);
         if (del[0].contains(curEnhancedStem))
         {
             res = res + s + "\n\n";
         }
        } catch(Exception e){
            // Do Something
      }
    }
      return res;
}
catch (Exception e) {
            // nothing to do here
        }   
    }
```

If you get exception it would be handled inside the loop but your loop will continue.

Comment: Oh, ill try this one! this may be the one I need! Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for that idea. The code now works properly! :)

Answer (score 3):

If you really want it to continue on the inner loop even after an error you could put another try block in there.

```
String delimiter = " - ";
String[] del;
String res = new String();

if(curEnhancedStem.startsWith("a"))
{
InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.definitiona); 
try {
  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
  String s = in.readLine();
  while(s != null)
    {
         try {
             s = in.readLine();
             del = s.split(delimiter);
             if (del[0].contains(curEnhancedStem))
             {
                 res = res + s + "\n\n";
             }
         }
         catch (Exception e) {
            // Error in string processing code (as opposed to IO) - Don't care... Continue
        }   
    }


    }
    return res;
}
catch (Exception e) {
        // nothing to do here
        }   
    }
```

Another idea is to use more specific Exceptions - not just the general catch all Exception

Comment: The outer try-catch block might be unecessary

Comment: I see... Didn't know that its possible to put multiple try/catches... ill try this one! Thank you!

Comment: Hi! The code works! Thanks a lot! I would've chosen this as best answer but AnujMathur_07 posted earlier by 4 mins. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in your `catch` clause. Try to add something like below for `while` loop(keep it in `try` block) as well to find out which `exception` u got:

```
catch(Exception e)
{
   Log.e("Exception here: "+ e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: the exception i get happens "if del[0] does not contains curEnhancedStem".

Comment: @JonelleAtienza then try to add try/catch block for while loop as well and get the message in DDMS and fix the issue..Happy Coding!!!

Comment: can not edit since the character count but should be , instead of + there